# How do I fix Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a `angular.js:14362 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: reportTypeServiceProvider <- reportTypeService <- ReportTypeController` error.

I've found a bunch of stuff about this, but I still can't figure out what the issue is in my code. Here it is:

pitchviz.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pitchviz', [
      'pitchviz.config',
      'pitchviz.routes',
      'pitchviz.report-types'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.config', []);

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.routes', ['ngRoute']);

  angular
    .module('pitchviz')
    .run(run);

  run.$inject = ['$http'];

  function run($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  }
})();
```

pitchviz.config.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.config')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];

  function config($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }
})();
```

pitchviz.routes.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.routes')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      controller: 'ReportTypeController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/report-types/report-types.html'
    }).otherwise('/');
  }
})();
```

report-types/report-types.modules.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.report-types', [
      'pitchviz.report-types.controllers',
      'pitchviz.report-types.services'
    ]);

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.report-types.controllers', []);

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.report-types.services', []);
})();
```

report-types/controllers/report-type.controller.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.report-types.controllers')
    .controller('ReportTypeController', ['reportTypeService', ReportTypeController]);

  ReportTypeController.$inject = ['reportTypeService'];

  function ReportTypeController(reportTypeService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.reportType = undefined;

    activate();

    function activate() {

      reportTypeService.get().then(reportTypeSuccess, reportTypeError);

      function accountSuccess(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        vm.reportType = data.data;
      }

      function reportTypeError(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

report-type/services/report-type.service.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pitchviz.report-types.services')
    .service('reportTypeService', ['reportTypeService', reportTypeService]);

  reportTypeService.$inject = ['$http'];

  function reportTypeService($http) {
    var reportTypeService = {
      get: get
    };

    return reportTypeService;

    function get() {
      console.log("service");
      return $http.get('/api/report-types/');
    }
  }
})();
```

What's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Ummm....woah, your syntax here is super confusing. If you're going to use $inject, use only $inject, don't also inject via array (examples here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#separate-data-calls). It's super hard to tell what's even going on here. Seems like you're trying to inject reportTypeService into reportTypeService, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Whatever services, controllers etc. you have created have you injected in index.html file.This type of error generally occurs  when angular could not find one of the dependency you are injecting.

Comment: `.service('reportTypeService', ['reportTypeService', reportTypeService]);

  reportTypeService.$inject = ['$http'];` This doesn't look good. Just stick to one of them (and btw, inline annotation is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

One module per file is solid pattern, but the problem here is that it is used incorrectly here. Child modules should be defined in their files, e.g. report-type.controller.js:

```
  angular
    .module('pitchviz.report-types.controllers', [])
    .controller('ReportTypeController', ...)
```

Not in parent module file, report-types.modules.js.

Only this way it can be guaranteed that module units are there if modules are there, and module files can be loaded in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

`reportTypeService` in `pitchviz.report-types.services` module. But `ReportTypeController` in `pitchviz.report-types.controllers` module. I think `pitchviz.report-types.controllers` cannot identify `reportTypeService` because it is in separate module. If you want to access `reportTypeService` in `pitchviz.report-types.controllers` module. you have to add `reportTypeService` to `pitchviz.report-types.controllers` module or inject `pitchviz.report-types.services` module to `pitchviz.report-types.controllers` module.

```
angular.module("pitchviz.report-types.controllers", ["pitchviz.report-types.services"]);
```

Comment: Not really. Once pitchviz.report-types is loaded in main module, it doesn't matter which module reportTypeService belongs to. This cannot cause the error here. But it is useful to define module dependency as you've shown, it is a good practice to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** Here, problem is in `report-types/controllers/report-type.controller.js` as you are making a `confusable` syntax there.

- No need to inject the service using `$inject` as you already inject that using an array.

**Remove this :** `ReportTypeController.$inject = ['reportTypeService'];`

**Simply use this :**

```
.controller('ReportTypeController', ['reportTypeService', ReportTypeController]);

function ReportTypeController(reportTypeService) {
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```